# what does `(this as any)` mean in this typescript snippet?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I meet this code and do not understand exactly what it does :

```js
public uploadItem(value:FileItem):void {
    let index = this.getIndexOfItem(value);
    let item = this.queue[index];
    let transport = this.options.isHTML5 ? '_xhrTransport' : '_iframeTransport';
    item._prepareToUploading();
    if (this.isUploading) {
      return;
    }
    this.isUploading = true;
    (this as any)[transport](item);
  }
```

Can anyone explain what does this  **(this as any)** statement do?

Comment: `this as any` is a cast. It casts the `this` to the `any` type (which also removes most compile time type checks)

Comment: It not casting @UnholySheep, this is assertion. Casting works in run time but assertion working on dev/compiling and has no side effects because it is a purely Typescript thing.

Comment: @Mouneer Microsoft themselves sometimes call it a cast (as in the [release notes of TypeScript 1.6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new-tsx-file-extension-and-as-operator)) so that's where my confusion of terms stemmed from

Comment: No wonder, I feel they always intend to confuse us :D

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**(this as any )** is just a **[Type Assertion](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion)** that works on dev/compiling time and has no side effects on run time because it is purely a Typescript thing. It can be useful if something related to `this` like `this[whatever]` which outputs a TS error because `whatever` is not defined inside the `this` TS type. So, this error can be suppressed with `(this as any)[whatever]`

**Also** `(this as any)` is the equivalent to `(<any> this)`

**Note to mention:** `--suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` as a [compiler option](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) suppresses those kind of possible errors.

Comment: What is the reason to explicitly assert `(<any> this)`? It looks like it is unnecessary.

Comment: @BorisD.Teoharov , The 'any' type is a powerful way to work with existing JavaScript, allowing you to gradually opt-in and opt-out of type-checking during compilation. For example, `(<any> this).myProperty)` where `this` can be the `window` object or any other thirdparty library with no type definitions.

Answer (score 5):

It can be actually written as

```
 (<any>this)[transport](item);
```

The  type casting is exhibited in the above statement!