# What does ...{} as any in react?

Tags: react-router, material-ui

I was having trouble passing the `to` to the Link component of `react-router-dom` in the Tab element of the `material-ui core`.

I finally came up with this solution:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

interface Props { 
  title?: string;
}
interface State {
   value: number;
}

class NavButtons extends React.Component<Props, State>  {
   constructor(props: Props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { value: 0 };
   }

   public handleOnChange = (event: any, value: number) => {
      this.setState({ value })
   }

   public render() {

      const {value} = this.state

      return (
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={this.handleOnChange} >
          <Tab label="Home" component={Link} {...{to:"/"} as any} />
          <Tab label="Contact" component={Link} {...{to:"/contact/"} as any} />
        </Tabs>
      )
   }
}

export default NavButtons
```

The only problem is that I can't seem to find out what `...{} as any` does in the documentation of material-ui or react.

Can someone explain this to me? I see a lot of React programmers use it but I have no idea what it does exactly.

Comment: Looks like it is spreading props onto a component.  It is destructuring an object that is created on the fly (with a type of `any`).

Comment: Did you find some documentation? I know what it looks like but I don't know this style of programming. And why cast it to any?

Comment: probably to satisfy some linter/TypeScript warning.  There is no difference between `<Tab label="Home" component={Link} {...{to:"/"} as any} />` and `<Tab label="Home" component={Link} to="/" />` but they insist on using an object to define these props (probably part of a tutorial?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[typescript. what is mean: (this as any)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551681/typescript-what-is-mean-this-as-any)

Looks like it's a TypeScript syntax. Adding `as any` could remove the type checking of `{to:"/"}` so it won't cause any warning/error.