# Type "json" | undefined not satisfied by "json" in Angular HttpClient

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I'm scrutinizing the [docs for `HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient), focusing on the [`get(...)`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) method. I've prepared the following sample:

```
const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
const observe: HttpObserve = null;
const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
const reportProgress = false;
const responseType = "json";
const withCredentials = true;

const options = {
  headers, observe, params,
  reportProgress, responseType, withCredentials
};

this.http.get(url, options)
```

I get an error stating the following.

```
No overload matches this call.  
The last overload gave the following error.  
Argument of type '{ responseType: string; ... }'  
is not assignable to parameter of type '{ responseType?: "json" | undefined; ... }'.  
Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json" | undefined'.
```

It's pretty obvious what's the reported issue. However, I don't see how *what I typed* is in validation towards *what is required*. If I type `undefined` as the value for `responseType`, the compiler is satisfied. In fact, the elaborated code samples (number 7, 8 and 12 through 15) explicitly state that it's the syntax to be used.

How is my `"json"` not the required `"json"`?

Comment: Because responseType is typed as *string*, that's what the error message tells you. It's not typed as the string literal type `"json"`.

Comment: It should have been inferred as the literal type since [TS 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#better-inference-for-literal-types), though - what version are you using?

Comment: @jonrsharpe My VSCode says v3.9.4 at the bottom. When I ran *tsc --version*, I got an error but it's likely due to being in the wrong directory. I trust VSC on this one. Also, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by *literal type* so I'll google it. I thought that a *string literal type* and a constant *string* were different names for the same concept.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types - `"json"` is a `string` but not all `string` are `"json"`.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: By literal type he means type `json` instead of `string`. One workaround could be `const responseType = "json" as "json";`

Comment: It works in 3.9.2 on the playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAFjMBzAFHADlAZwC5EBvRPWBAfhIHIArAhOxAXwEoy2AoHiBASgV88JAF5EjZmDoBuPqnTZylMew4KgA. Could be a bug in 3.9.4, maybe see if anyone's reported it.

Comment: @MichaelD prefer `const responseType: "json" = "json";` - then the *actual value* gets checked (compare `const foo = "bar" as "baz"`).

Comment: @MichaelD I feel a bit retarded now. Are you saying that my string should contain a valid JSON syntax (i.e. brackets, properties, colons and value, e.g. `{a:1}`)? Also, `as "json"` felt unfamiliar to me. As far my competence reaches, there's no `Json` type/class in TS. Or is it som black magic (black magic to ignorant me, that is) saying that the type is *whatever*, where said *whatever* happens to be *"json"* sequence of characters?

Comment: @KonradViltersten no they're not saying that at all, just missing quotes from `"json"`. If you don't know what `as <type>` means read up on [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). You really need to know TS basics to be effective in Angular.

Comment: Oh I get it, it's because `{ responseType }` widens to `{ responseType: string }` - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAFjMBzAFHADlAZwC5EBvRPWBAfhIHIArAhOxAXwEoy2AoHiBASgV88JAF5EjZmDoBuPgLBCRVZYknlKY9gp6p02bYI4KgA.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Not exactly. Think of string literal type (`json` here) with union types (`"json" | "text" | ...`) akin to enums. So the `responseType` should have the exact string `"json"`. But for some reason (which I too don't understand yet), it's being inferred as type `string` in your case. So one solution would be to assert the type using the [`as <type>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42551933/6513921) syntax or better as @jonrsharpe suggested define the type before assigning the value: `const responseType: "json" = "json";`.

Comment: @KonradViltersten it's literally on the "basic types" page...

Comment: @MichaelD I must admit, I feel a weird satisfaction and relaxation of the mind when other developers whom I trust say things like "*I **too** don't understand*" as it provides me the notion of not being a single dumb dude on the block but actually hitting something that's at least a little bit confusing. I hate being the **only** confusee.   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpClient` methods use [*string literal types*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) for some of the options - rather than just declaring e.g. `responseType` as the generic `string` they provide the specific *values* it can take. So why does your `options` object *not* meet the type definition, given it has one of the accepted values?

The initial declaration:

```
const responseType = "json";
```

defines `responseType` as the string literal type `"json"`; it's a `const`, it can only ever have that single value. So far, so good. However, the *object* declaration:

```
const options = { responseType /* etc. */ };
```

gives `options` the type `{ responseType: string }`, it *widens* the type of the attribute. It does this because objects are *mutable*, so you could change the value.

To fix this, you have several options; in no particular order:

- Inline the object creation:

  ```
   this.http.get(url, { responseType });
  ```

  This doesn't widen the type, because you can't assign a different value into an object you don't hold a reference to.
- Explicitly type the intermediate object:

  ```
   const options: { responseType: "json" } = { ... };
  ```
- Use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the *object*:

  ```
   const options = { responseType } as const;  // or = <const>{...};
  ```

  This tells the compiler you aren't going to change the values and gives `options` the type `{ readonly responseType: "json" }`.
- Use a `const` assertion on the *string* (suggested by [Michael D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62651724/type-json-undefined-not-satisfied-by-json-in-angular-httpclient/62652353#comment110796192_62652353)):

  ```
  const responseType = "json" as const;  // or = <const>"json";
  ```

  This one's a bit weird, because the type of `responseType` is still `"json"`, as it was originally. However this creates a *"`const` context"* in which that type is *non-widening*, so the resulting type of `options` is `{ responseType: "json" }` (not `readonly` as above, but you can only assign that one value to it).

Here is a playground showing the various options for `options`: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAFjMBzAFHADrBAZwC5EBvRAJwFNDcjqAVAT12oH5SByAK0IS6IAvgEpyQgFASIRKFVr0whJq2qIAvIl78wXANzTZiMAgDqMACbUw6DACUFDFmw1a+AxAENCiGUqgGhv6IeARKrhQ0dE6qwgZ+hHJQqhYA8vjwSqSRjkoqbNzuusIR8tF5zmpC8UYJUOlhPpo55cqVJd6+sjXBnlBQlDAARiBQ1ADCsg2ZTeRlim2qpCZg5lY2mA6t+VWBqLY4GUQiBvuYWC0LO8InEmfYyWxpR0q391h108enaOd9A8NRhMpi9CLcgA).

Comment: This is rather interesting. I'd also add the type cast solution: `<const>'json'`.

Comment: @MichaelD that does seem to work, `const responseType = <const>"json"` (or `"json" as const` to use the syntax in the answer), but I don't understand *why* so I don't really want to add it - the type of `responseType` doesn't change, it's still `"json"`, but that `<const>` seems to impact the object creation too, that metadata somehow stays with the value. It makes the `options` type `{ responseType: "json" }`, which isn't `readonly` like `as const` on the object but can still only take that one value.

Comment: @MichaelD alright I figured it out and added it, thanks!