# Argument of type {stringVariable} not assignable to object of type {string literal}

Tags: typescript

I have the following code, which takes an options parameter:

```
const getCat = function (options: { format: "decimal" }) {
    return null
}
const options = { format: "decimal" }
const cat = getCat(options)
```

However, the `const cat = getCat(options)` runs into an error:

```
Argument of type '{ format: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ format: "decimal"; }'.
  Types of property 'format' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"decimal"'.
```

How can I cast my options to be of the type TypeScript is looking for?

Comment: Directly pass it into the call: `getCat({ format: "decimal" })` or declare an actual type for the parameter.

Comment: Why does passing it directly work?

Comment: Because then the type doesn't get widened, because there's no reference through which that value could be changed. `options` is infered as `{ format: string }` unless you add `as const` (either to the object or the string) [related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62652353/3001761].

Comment: @PatrickCollins Because then TS knows the type is `{ format: "decimal" }` and not just any string. If you declare a type you can also do `const options: MyType = /* ... */` to get the same effect.

Comment: Well that worked splended! So typescript won't just detect the typing works?

Comment: _"typescript won't just detect the typing works?"_ - what? It _does_ detect that the typing _doesn't_ work, because `options` could get changed before `getCat` gets called - objects are mutable. If `options.format` can only have that one value, or a smaller range than `string`, you need to tell the compiler so it can help enforce that requirement.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "typescript won't auto convert/cast the typing for you". I see. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

1. Send the options right to the function:

   ```js
   const cat = getCat({ format: "decimal" })
   ```
2. Declare a type and have `options` be that type

   ```js
   type MyType = { format: "decimal" }
   const options: MyType = { format: "decimal" }
   const cat = getCat(options)
   ```

Comment: You have at least 3, because there are various uses of [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) that work too.

Comment: Could you add the third?

Comment: I explained why this happens and various options (including these two) in the post I linked to above