# How to achieve type compatibility for a discriminated union field

Tags: typescript

I have the following  minimal code that I've copied from a blog (it's adapted slightly):

```
interface Cat {
  name: string;
  color: 'tabby' | 'calico' | 'black' | 'white' | 'bald';
  kittens?: number;
}

const properCat = {
  name: 'Chomosuke',
  color: 'black'
}

const accept = (cat: Cat) => {
  //Not important for this discussion
}

accept(properCat);
```

With reference to the code here above, initially I was surprised to find that it doesn't compile, getting the error:

```
 Types of property 'color' are incompatible.
   Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"tabby" | "calico" | "black" | "white" | "bald"'.
```

I realized this is indeed true, as even though properCat is const, its members are still modifiable, and hence I could do e.g. `properCat.color = 'red'` after creation, which would imply it breaks the type-safety constraints for Cat.

The type of code below would not break these rules, however I suspect readonly is a typescript keyword, while object literals is a javascript concept, and hence readonly does not compile in this context, disallowing me to address the structural incompatibility:

```
const properCat = {
  readonly name: 'Chomosuke',
  readonly color: 'black'
}
```

What would the best way be, without explicitly stating that properCat is a Cat, to achieve structural compatibility that would cause properCat to be accepted as Cat? More specifically, how can I modify the object literal's color member to be type compatible?

Comment: Note describing that as a "const object" could be confusing, given [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) which _do_ make the properties read-only. Related, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62651724/3001761

Comment: I'll change that when I'm back at the PC

Comment: @jcalz, I was initially surprised that it didn't compile. I then realised it was because the type of color need not fall within the set of permissible values, whereafter I was surprised that I could not specify read only fields in an object literal. I don't think the context detracts from the question, but I'll change it. Perhaps Const assertions would work, but not being allowed to specify read-only for a literal is interesting

Comment: @jcalz I've edited the question. I hope it is clearer. You are right, my original problem was not the specifying of readonly in literal types, however I thought that would have solved the original problem and I expected that possible. That said I suspect (as I've stated) it's because object literals themselves are "inherited" from JS, whereas readonly is isolated to TS. I haven't studied the Obejct.freeze answer here below, but if freeze just has a runtime impact, I would suspect that the code would still not compiler correctly (I haven't tested this yet).

Comment: (Indeed, `readonly` is part of TS and there is no shorthand to annotate or modify property types inside an object literal value.)  As for the actual question: could you look [at this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wy2eKw) and tell me if that meets your needs? It tells the compiler that it should use `Cat` as a context for inferring `properCat`, so it infers `{name: string, color: "black"}` instead of `{name: string, color: string}`. If it meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz from a coupling perspective, I'd say strictly speaking properCat doesn't have to know about Cat to be structurally compatible. I can see the benefit of satisfies in certain circumstances from [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/typescript-satisfies-operator/). For me the object freezing is a better solution in this instance. I think satisfies definitely answers the question, but not without unnecessary coupling. I'd would however upmark that too, and I've learnt something no doubt.

Comment: @jcalz for the sake of others, dependency diagram for [satisfies](https://www.planttext.com/api/plantuml/svg/SoWkIImgAStDuIf8JCvEJ4zLK79EB57mpKyfpKbLKgZcKb281Wh4SjLo8LGK5EKNf1PXg8CBewfEJ4vEBK1J2X43gqFIfg2dPmUnJi5A8IMr83KlfLWXFuyBfXoNl0EG0V820000) vs. [freeze](https://www.planttext.com/api/plantuml/svg/SoWkIImgAStDuIf8JCvEJ4zLK79EB57mpKyfpKbLKgZcKb281Wh4SjLo8LGK5EKNf1PXg8CBewfEJ4vEBK1J2X43guEn5VJqx21sALWffAGMfEQb52lavt4v01aWzm40) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the type is derived from the object literal, which evaluates to a mutable object. If you want `properCat` to refer to an immutable object, you can simply freeze it:

```
const properCat = Object.freeze({
  name: 'Chomosuke',
  color: 'black'
});
```

Comment: `as const` assertion would have a similar effect. However, it won't be enforced at runtime.

Comment: This does indeed inforce read-onlyness of fields and make the types structurally compatible. It is also typesafe in terms of the original type. I might give this an up mark