# Difference between {} and {} as any in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript

I am new to TypeScript. What is the difference between the below (`foo` and `foo2`) and (`foo3` and `foo4`)?

(`foo` and `foo2`) and (`foo3` and `foo4`) print the same values but at compile time, a red line is shown under `foo2` and `foo3`.

[image]

```
interface Foo {
    name: string;
}

const foo: Foo = {} as any;
const foo2: Foo = {};
const foo3: Foo = null;
const foo4: Foo = null as any;

console.log(foo);   // {}
console.log(foo2);  // {}
console.log(foo3);  // null
console.log(foo4);  // null
```

Comment: Have you not answered your own question? Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551681/what-does-this-as-any-mean-in-this-typescript-snippet?

Comment: `as any` removes type check, you try to assign a non Foo value to a constant you say should be a Foo type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does \`(this as any)\` mean in this typescript snippet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551681/what-does-this-as-any-mean-in-this-typescript-snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are purely a compiler concept, they mean nothing and no longer exist at runtime so you will never see anything in a console.log to relates to your interface. Interfaces are for typing objects in your IDE while developing so you get typing support, error and code completion from the compiler. That is the point of TypeScript, once the code is compiled it is just plain old JavaScript and the interfaces no longer exist.

The `as` keyword is used to tell the compiler to treat the object as a different type than it infers it to be.